# Ip address retrieving

Tags: c#, ip-address

There is an error showing at this line on execution:

```
((IPEndPoint)(TcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint)).Address;
```

the eroor is:

```
An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Client.get  ...
```

What is solution for this error?

The code is shown below.

```
//Assume myList is an ArrayList
IPAddress tempAddress = ((IPEndPoint)(TcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint)).Address;
myList.Add(tempAddress);
```

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve the IP address of? ... the local machine?

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because the property RemoteEndPoint is an instance member of TCPClient. This means that you must instantiate a TCPClient (you must "new it") before you can access the RemoteEndPoint.

If you want more help, you need to post the preceeding lines of code so that we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: i solved the above problem, but got the new one, that is shown here.
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " This error showing at this line

 IPAddress ipAddress = ((IPEndPoint)(tClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint)).Address;

Answer (score 0):

do you have an instance of **TcpClient** ?

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler error states you need an instance of [IPEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx) to access the Address property.

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry ("www.contoso.com").AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (ipAddress, 11004);
IPAddress tempAddress = ipEndPoint.Address;
myList.Add(tempAddress);
```